# Can we use multiple camera-tag's video tag with same id?

Tags: php, camera

```
<html>
  <body>
       <div>
            <video id="eb" data-uuid="<?php echo $expamle[0]['video_name'] ?>"/>
       </div>
       <div>
            <video id="eb" data-uuid="<?php echo $expamle[1]['video_name'] ?>"/>
       </div>
 </body>
```

I am using camera-tag API to upload video how can I use multiple video tags with same id but different video

Comment: First it is video tag not camera tag ( i think ). Then It is suggested that id should be unique on HTML DOM. While css class can be used for multiple element for treat as collection.

Comment: camera tag is a API in which they just provide a single line "camera tag" to record or upload videos and "video tag" to play the uploaded video but I want to use it multiple times as I am uploading multiple videos.